# How to find barrier function's implementation?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to implement new barrier function.

First of all, I want to know about default barrier implementation. (phtread, linux)

And I find pthread.h (/usr/include)

But in this file I can't find barrier implementation. only declaration.

```
1040 /* Functions to handle barriers.  */                                       
1041 
1042 /* Initialize BARRIER with the attributes in ATTR.  The barrier is
1043    opened when COUNT waiters arrived.  */
1044 extern int pthread_barrier_init (pthread_barrier_t *__restrict __barrier,
1045                  __const pthread_barrierattr_t *__restrict
1046                  __attr, unsigned int __count)
1047      __THROW __nonnull ((1));
1048 
1049 /* Destroy a previously dynamically initialized barrier BARRIER.  */
1050 extern int pthread_barrier_destroy (pthread_barrier_t *__barrier)
1051      __THROW __nonnull ((1));
1052 
1053 /* Wait on barrier BARRIER.  */
1054 extern int pthread_barrier_wait (pthread_barrier_t *__barrier)
1055      __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

Please teach me where is barrier function implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source code of PThread Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224252/source-code-of-pthread-library)

Answer (score 6):

The glibc barrier implementation is in the files [`pthread_barrier_init.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_barrier_init.c;h=1aaa2a4eb0b1fc974680d50205214fe9fa1e2280;hb=HEAD), [`pthread_barrier_wait.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_barrier_wait.c;h=89936a08c7e9fbb51d4eeb24b7f1619a059e0b39;hb=HEAD) and [`pthread_barrier_destroy.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_barrier_destroy.c;h=6808d36da261f1b12e47d56a2c0069ca21c5aefe;hb=HEAD).  The pseudocode implementation in [`DESIGN-barrier.txt`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/DESIGN-barrier.txt;h=23463c6b7e77231697db3e13933b36ce295365b1;hb=HEAD) is probably also of interest.

Answer (score 3):

http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0201633922/sourcecode/barrier.c

Look how int barrier_wait (barrier_t *barrier) uses a counter to track the number of pending threads.

Comment: Just a note: I believe this is example code from "Programming with POSIX Threads" by David R. Butenhof.

Comment: Seems so, any idea what the license is on the code examples in that book?